# Parsing NSString to NSDate object

Tags: nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am trying to parse the following NSString to an NSDate object:

"Sat, 21 Jan 2012 13:06:00 +0100"

I know that I need the following lines of code to do this:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEE, MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss GMT"];
NSDate *dateObject = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateString];
```

But since dateObject always has the value nil, I assume that the expression inside the dateFormatter is not correct.
Does anyone have a suggestion for the right formatter statement?
Have already tried a lot of options, but none of them seems to work.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your date format is wrong. it should be:

```
EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss GMT
```

for

```
Sat, 21 Jan 2012 13:06:00 +0100
```

You've accidentally exchanged "dd" and "MMM".

Comment: Got it. The correct date format is: "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZZ" Thanks a lot.